# Modelica buildings outputs error when connecting the terminal

Tags: modelica, openmodelica, dymola

I am trying to connect the grid to a line in the modelica building.electrical library.
I get this error:

> [2] 18:20:02 Translation Error
> [Buildings.Electrical.AC.ThreePhasesBalanced.Lines.Line: 4:5-4:47]: Type mismatch in binding terminal_n = grid_connection, expected subtype of Buildings.Electrical.AC.ThreePhasesBalanced.Interfaces.Terminal_n, got type Buildings.Electrical.AC.ThreePhasesBalanced.Sources.Grid

I found this unusual since I am connecting it like the example which does not have an error

My code:

```
model building
  Buildings.Electrical.AC.ThreePhasesBalanced.Sources.Grid grid_connection annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-82, 60}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Buildings.Electrical.AC.ThreePhasesBalanced.Sources.PVSimpleOriented solar_array(A = 10)  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-106, 12}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 180)));
  Buildings.Electrical.AC.ThreePhasesBalanced.Loads.Resistive building_load annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-4, 12}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Buildings.Electrical.AC.ThreePhasesBalanced.Storage.Battery BESS(EMax = 1800000000, SOC_start = 20)  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-82, -46}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 270)));
  Buildings.Electrical.AC.ThreePhasesBalanced.Lines.Line grid_line(terminal_n = grid_connection)  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-40, 12}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

  Buildings.BoundaryConditions.WeatherData.ReaderTMY3 weather_data(filNam = "weather.mos")  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-184, 4}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.CombiTimeTable load_data(columns = 15:44640, fileName = "data.txt", tableOnFile = true, timeScale = 60, verboseRead = true)  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {29, 13}, extent = {{9, -9}, {-9, 9}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.CombiTimeTable bess_data annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-48, -46}, extent = {{8, -8}, {-8, 8}}, rotation = 0)));
equation
  connect(BESS.terminal, grid_line.terminal_n) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-82, -36}, {-48, -36}, {-48, 12}, {-50, 12}}, color = {255, 255, 255}));
  connect(grid_line.terminal_n, BESS.terminal) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-50, 12}, {-82, 12}, {-82, -36}}));
  connect(grid_line.terminal_n, solar_array.terminal) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-50, 12}, {-96, 12}}));
  connect(grid_line.terminal_p, building_load.terminal) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-30, 12}, {-14, 12}}));
  connect(load_data.y, building_load.Pow) annotation(
    Line(points = {{19, 13}, {13.5, 13}, {13.5, 12}, {6, 12}}, color = {0, 0, 127}));
  connect(bess_data.y, BESS.P) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-56, -46}, {-72, -46}}, color = {0, 0, 127}));
  connect(weather_data.weaBus, solar_array.weaBus) annotation();
  annotation(
    uses(Buildings(version = "9.1.0"), Modelica(version = "4.0.0")));
end building;
```

Example Code:

```
within Buildings.Electrical.Examples;
model RenewableSources
  AC.ThreePhasesBalanced.Sources.Grid gri(
    f=f,
    V=V_nominal,
    phiSou=0) "Grid model that provides power to the system"
  AC.ThreePhasesBalanced.Lines.Line line1(mode=Buildings.Electrical.Types.CableMode.automatic,
      l=1500,
    V_nominal=V_nominal,
    P_nominal=7*(PLoa_nominal + PSun) + PWin) "Electrical line"
              annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-80,10},{-60,30}})));
equation
  connect(gri.terminal, line1.terminal_n) annotation (Line(
      points={{-90,40},{-90,20},{-80,20}},
      color={0,120,120},
      smooth=Smooth.None));
```

Thank you all for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I found:

- There are two connections from `BESS.terminal` to `grid_line.terminal.n`. One of them is white, so likely this is the reason it wasn't noticed.
- The modifier `grid_connection` in `grid_line` for `terminal_n` does not make sense to me. I guess it should be removed.
- The connection between `bess_data.y[]` and `BESS.P` is not correct, as the output of the table is a vector. It should be something like `connect(bess_data.y[1], BESS.P)`.
- The connection between `weather_data` and `solar_array` has no annotation and is therefore invisible.
- I had to change `weather_data.filNam` from `wheather.mos` to `Modelica.Utilities.Files.loadResource("modelica://Buildings/Resources/weatherdata/USA_CA_San.Francisco.Intl.AP.724940_TMY3.mos")` as the used script is not provided here.
- Removed modifier from `load_data.columns`.

If you then connect `grid_connection` to any of the electric components and add data for the two tabled, the model should work.

The result is...

```
model building
  Buildings.Electrical.AC.ThreePhasesBalanced.Sources.Grid grid_connection annotation (
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin={-20,48},    extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Buildings.Electrical.AC.ThreePhasesBalanced.Sources.PVSimpleOriented solar_array(A = 10)  annotation (
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin={-44,0},      extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 180)));
  Buildings.Electrical.AC.ThreePhasesBalanced.Loads.Resistive building_load annotation (
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin={58,0},     extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Buildings.Electrical.AC.ThreePhasesBalanced.Storage.Battery BESS(EMax = 1800000000, SOC_start = 20)  annotation (
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin={-20,-58},    extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 270)));
  Buildings.Electrical.AC.ThreePhasesBalanced.Lines.Line grid_line(l=1e3, P_nominal=1e4) annotation (
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin={22,0},      extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

  Buildings.BoundaryConditions.WeatherData.ReaderTMY3 weather_data(filNam=Modelica.Utilities.Files.loadResource("modelica://Buildings/Resources/weatherdata/USA_CA_San.Francisco.Intl.AP.724940_TMY3.mos"))
    annotation (Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin={-82,-40}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.CombiTimeTable load_data(table=[0.0,0.0; 1,0.0], fileName = "data.txt", timeScale = 60, verboseRead = true)  
    annotation (Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin={91,0}, extent = {{9, -9}, {-9, 9}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.CombiTimeTable bess_data(table=[0.0,0.0; 1,0.0])
    annotation (Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin={14,-58}, extent = {{8, -8}, {-8, 8}}, rotation = 0)));
equation 
  connect(grid_line.terminal_n, BESS.terminal) annotation (
    Line(points={{12,0},{-20,0},{-20,-48}}));
  connect(grid_line.terminal_n, solar_array.terminal) annotation (
    Line(points={{12,0},{-34,0}}));
  connect(grid_line.terminal_p, building_load.terminal) annotation (
    Line(points={{32,0},{48,0}}));
  connect(load_data.y, building_load.Pow) annotation (
    Line(points={{81.1,0},{68,0}}, color = {0, 0, 127}));
  connect(bess_data.y[1], BESS.P) annotation (
    Line(points={{5.2,-58},{-10,-58}}, color={0,0,127}));
  connect(grid_connection.terminal, solar_array.terminal)
    annotation (Line(points={{-20,38},{-20,0},{-34,0}},   color={0,120,120}));
  connect(weather_data.weaBus, solar_array.weaBus)
    annotation (Line(
      points={{-72,-40},{-44,-40},{-44,-9}},
      color={255,204,51},
      thickness=0.5));
  annotation (
    uses(Buildings(version = "9.1.0"), Modelica(version = "4.0.0")));
end building;
```

...which at least works, but I would NOT trust the results it generates. At best, this is a starting point to understand which errors were made when creating the model (which is why the above list is added) and to do better next time.

**Disclaimer:** The model is still a pretty big mess (incompatible units, unset parameters etc.) and it would probably make sense to start from scratch...